# Internal keyboard and trackpad stop working after plugging in USB device

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I got a new MacBook Pro with OS X Mavericks. When connecting my phone via USB, the internal keyboard and the trackpad immediately stop working -- not always but in most cases. The bluetooth mouse and an external USB keyboard are not affected. Everything else works also fine. The power button of the internal keyboard still works. Reboot helps. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: Does this happen equally often using either USB port, or does it only happen using one or the other?

Comment: It happened reproducible with both USB ports. But the problem seems to be gone - I have currently no problem connecting the phone. I'm not aware of any change - perhaps a (silent) software update.

Comment: I've the exact same problem, and it can be infuriating.  I'm a mobile developer, and when at home, don't have another keyboard and mouse to use, so when it happens, I have to do a hard reset to get things back to normal.

About 20% of the time everything disables, I'm able to get it back by unplugging, and plugging the phone back in, but the rest of the time, only possibility is the hard reset.

In work I use a plugged in keyboard and Magic Mouse, and sometimes after debugging on my phone everything's disabled, and I only realise when I get home.

Comment: Same issue on my end with Dell 2415 monitor.. just putting note here in case others have issue with dell monitor. I've removed Android File Transfer, hoping that'll resolve issue.

Comment: Same issue here, a mobile dev, both ports, and only corrects itself sometimes when plugging the device back in.  Note that I can connect an external keyboard/mouse and use those just fine.  I'd recommend keeping a spare for this situation.

Answer (score 52):

Yes, the culprit is the Android File Transfer application. And following the steps outlined [here](https://cooltrainer.org/taming-android-file-transfer-on-mac-os-x/) (disabling the annoying Android File Transfer Agent) seems to solve this. (No need to completely remove it, as it may be useful)

The underlying issue is logged with the developers as [58416: Android File Transfer - Mac 10.8.4 AppleUSBMultitouchDriver Keyboard Input Delays](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58416).

Comment: I think the above is correct, as this had never happened before I started using that application a few days ago (though it just happened to me for the first time today). Plugging a mouse into the USB port got my trackpad and keyboard working again, btw.

Comment: Below, @SteveTauber links to an issue filed against Android File Transfer. Voting for the issue might encourage Google to fix their bug.

Comment: I have had this issue since a long time ago, and I knew it it had something to do with the Android File Transfer App. This is awesome thank you for the steps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same intermittent problem when connecting my Nexus 4. I did some research and narrowed down my logs to the following:

```
Jun 10 01:22:30 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=971[ksadmin] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
Jun 10 01:22:30 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=976[ksadmin] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
Jun 10 01:22:31 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=977[ksadmin] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
Jun 10 01:22:31 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::message - kIOUSBMessagePortHasBeenReset.
Jun 10 01:22:37 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19914. 97    AppleUSBEHCI::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5000 milliseconds on bus 0x1d, timing out! (Addr: 4, EP: 0)
Jun 10 01:22:37 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe0004051 - retrying
Jun 10 01:22:37 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
Jun 10 01:22:37 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe000404f (interface 1, reportID 0xac, payload 2
Jun 10 01:22:37 Steves-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceSetReport returned an error in configureDataMode
Jun 10 01:23:25 Steves-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[60]: magsafeStateChanged state changed old 1 new 2
Jun 10 01:24:26 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1402356266 0
```

From what I can tell this is essentially that the AppleUSBMultitouchDriver is crashing. Then it tries to restart the daemon in charge and finally bails out with an error. After that the keyboard and touchpad are non responsive.

I have tried to close the macbook (putting it into sleep mode), then waking it up. This does not fix the problem. However, I found this thread discussing conflicting with the Android File Transfer app:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58416

Do you have an Android device?

Older issues occur from a hardware issue (circa 2009). In my case I have a faulty cable which causes the connection to drop/reconnect every now and then. This causes an increase in the chances of the software malfunction occurring.

Comment: Thanks for posting the logs, I see similar ones when plugging other USB devices.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when I plug in my Nexus 5. The only solution that I have found other than restarting my computer is to unplug and then plug back in my phone until the trackpad and keyboard start responding. This can take a few tries but it is faster then restarting your computer.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had this problem and removing Android File Transfer from OS X seems to resolve the problem for me.

Comment: Wow didn't realize the problems started around the time I installed that. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. For those reporting rebooting as a fix, just want to suggest something that I found out. After several frustrating reboots, I realized if I just plugged/unplugged the USB cable in question several times I eventually get control of mouse/keyboard back.

Still super annoying, especially if I don't realize it's in this state and walk away from my desk (where the USB cable is).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to plug in a powered USB hub and see if the issue persists?

I would also suggest resetting the SMC just in case, you can find that [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same intermittent issue with my Sony Experia SP (model C5303) and the only solution I have found apart from a hard re-boot (hold down the power key for 5 seconds or more) is to unplug and re-plug the USB connection until the keyboard and trackpad kick back in - really frustrating in a professional environment.

I am running Maveric 10.9.4 and this happens daily.